# Selecting every nth observation by groups pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code which generates a dataframe. I want to be able to select every nth  based on a 'group' classification as in df1 and df2.

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = [['Orange',11], ['Orange',12], ['Orange',13], ['Orange',14] 
            ['Orange',15], ['Orange',16], ['Orange',17], ['Orange',18], 
            ['StrawBerry',22], ['StrawBerry',23], ['StrawBerry',24], 
            ['StrawBerry',25], ['StrawBerry',26], ['StrawBerry',27]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Fruit', 'Score'])
    df

    #Here I start from the 1st row and then move to the fourth and then 
    #and so forth by Fruit.
    Output1data = [['Orange',11], ['Orange',14], ['Orange',17], 
                  ['StrawBerry',22], ['StrawBerry',25]]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(Output1data,columns=['Fruit','Score'])
    df1

    #Here I start from the second row onwards and then move to the fifth and 
    #then eighth and so forth by Fruit 
    Output2data = [['Orange',12], ['Orange',15], ['Orange',18], 
                   ['StrawBerry',23], ['StrawBerry',26]]
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(Output2data,columns=['Fruit','Score'])
    df2
```

Please let me know if there is a way to do this using the group classification because I need to select every nth row for a given starting point ?

Thanks a lot in advance. Really appreciate this.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Xnkr : my desired output is df1 and df2 . Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: I want to create df1 and df2 from the 'data' dataframe (without needing to write out Ouput1data and Output2data code).

Comment: what do you mean  "  every nth based on a 'group' classification "

Comment: I mean starting from the first observation of Orange, then the first observation of Strawberry

Comment: I do not want to select every nth row from the overall dataframe. I want to do it from the first observation for each 'group' in this case 'Fruit'

Comment: Thanks to @steboc as well for helping me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with modulo by `3` to helper `Series` and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.groupby('Fruit')['Fruit'].cumcount() % 3
print (s)
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     0
4     1
5     2
6     0
7     1
8     0
9     1
10    2
11    0
12    1
13    2
dtype: int64

df1 = df[s == 0]
print (df1)
         Fruit  Score
0       Orange     11
3       Orange     14
6       Orange     17
8   StrawBerry     22
11  StrawBerry     25

df2 = df[s == 1]
print (df2)
         Fruit  Score
1       Orange     12
4       Orange     15
7       Orange     18
9   StrawBerry     23
12  StrawBerry     26
```

Comment: @cordelia - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Comment: @jerael . Yes I gave it the tick.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code, and modify parameters  ( start and step )

```
start = 0
step = 3
selection = [x for x in range(start,len(df),step) ]
new_df = df.iloc[selection,:]
```

Comment: But that gives me Strawberry 23 and Strawberry26 when what I need is Strawberry 22 and Strawberry 25

Answer (score 0):

Slower than cordelia's answer, but without math:

```
def everyNth(df,N,startIdx):
    dfNew = df.groupby('Fruit').apply(lambda x: 
               x.iloc[startIdx::N])
    return dfNew.reset_index(level='Fruit',drop=True)
```